# PostThreadMessage equivalent on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos, core-foundation

I am porting an application to Mac OS X.

I need to do following task on Mac OS X too. A thread A needs to post a message to message queue of another thread B. These message involves some custom messages too.
On a particular message like EXIT_LOOP, thread B comes out of message loop.

I have started message loop for thread B using CFRunLoop.

Now I cannot find how thread A can post a message to thread B.

In Windows, this is possible PostThreadMessage. There may not be straight port to Mac OS X for this, but there must be a way to do it on Mac OS X.

Please note that thread B does not know about thread A, but thread A knows thread B.

Windows Code:

```
MessageLoop () {
    MSG message;
    BOOL ret;
    while(ret = GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
        if(ret == -1)
            break;

         if(UseMessage(message) = EXIT)
             break;

    }

}

int UseMessage (MSG Message)
{
   switch(Message) {

   //Process various messages.

   case I_AM_COMPLETE:
       return EXIT;

   }
}


//Thread A:
MessageLoop ();
//Cleanup

//Thread B:
PostThreadMessage(threadidofA, I_AM_COMPLETE, 0, 0);
```

I believe this code may give more clarity. I want equivalent functionality on Mac OS X.

Comment: What's wrong with any old collection class and some thread locking?

Comment: I am quite new to Mac OS X. I do not know how to achieve this on Mac OS X. I just want equivalent functionality on Mac OS X. If it is possible using thread locking, please post an example.

Comment: To make it more clear, I have added code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general bit of advice, you should take a different tack for your porting effort. Don't try to "transliterate" Win32 coding strategies to Mac ones. Revamp your design for Mac coding techniques from the ground up.

Anyway, there are various ways to achieve something similar. Probably the simplest requires that thread B use `NSRunLoop` rather than `CFRunLoop`. Then, thread A can use `-[NSObject performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]` to run a method on thread B.

Comment: I am not maintaing NSThread object. Thread A only has id of Thread B. Please provide solution in CFRunLoop or using Posix threads (such  as locks). Even if it requires implementing custom run loop source, I can do it.

Comment: There's almost nothing of interest you can do with just the thread ID. Why do you insist that you can only have a thread ID when that doesn't fulfill your program's needs? Any solution using locks or a custom run loop source will still require that you maintain a reference to some shared data structure. Once you accept that requirement, the your shared data structure may as well be an `NSThread` pointer. The method I suggested is surely implemented under the hood as a run loop source or timer of some kind. Why re-implement what's already provided?